# iPhone: Can't access all value from .plist file

Tags: iphone, plist, nsuserdefaults

I have a pretty simple root.plist file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>User Info</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Username</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>username_preference</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>IsSecure</key>
            <false/>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>Alphabet</string>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Password</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>password_preference</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>IsSecure</key>
            <true/>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>Alphabet</string>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Application Info</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Version</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>api_version_preference</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>2.0</string>
            <key>Value</key>
            <string>2.0</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

All the fields is shown when navigating to the relevant settings page in the iphone's settings application, but i can't access api_version_preference from my application.

I've tried to print out the .plist file as a dictionary and I only see the values from the username/password fields, so i'm probably doing something wrong. Here is what I use when printing the data:

```
NSLog(@"defs: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to supply defaults to NSUserDefaults. NSUserDefaults doesn't store the setting if you haven't changed (ie saved) it.

create a NSDictionary of default values and set it with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userDefaultsDefaults];`

like this:

```
NSDictionary *userdefaultsDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"2.0", @"api_version_preference",
                                      nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userdefaultsDefaults];
```

do this with all the settings you use from NSUserDefaults